# I can't edit my value with inputmask

Tags: jquery, input-mask

I wanna fill a field with three numbers. My mask was configured like  : ['009', '099', '999']. I wish to allow values like "001","011" or "111". But when I put values like "023" and give focus out e try edit again this value, to put "234",  the mask don't allow.  I belive that my first "0" is match with the "9" of mask, thus this way i can't edit.

There are any way to allow the edition or fill with 0 left until complete the three caracteres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [onBeforeWrite](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#onbeforewrite) option when configuring the field. This options allows pre-processing data before writing to the field.

Suppose that you have a text field called hello.

```
<input type="text" name="hello" id="hello">
```

To fill with leading-zeros on field, replace the masked values of the buffer parameter with zeros.

```
$("#hello").inputmask({
    mask: "999",
    numericInput: true,
    onBeforeWrite: function (event, buffer, caretPos, opts) {
        if (event !== undefined && event.type === "blur") {
            for (var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
                if (buffer[i] == "_")
                    buffer[i] = '0';
            };
        }
    }
});
```